# Supported way to configure the Authentication Provider Selection page in SharePoint 2016

Tags: forms-authentication, custom, solution-package

We have a SharePoint 2016 farm with both form-based authentication (FBA) and Active Directory Federated Services (ADFS) configured. This means that when unauthenticated users navigate to the site, they are first presented with a drop-down asking them what method they want to use to log-in: FBA or ADFS. The URL of this page (at least for us) is: https://mysharepointsite/_login/default.aspx

We have created a solution to customise this page, where we added our ocmpany logo and replace the dropdown with big buttons (touch friendly). However when deploying the solution at the moment we are replacing this /_login/default.aspx page, because I couldn't for the heck of me find a supported way to configure SharePoint to use an alternative page instead.

We know how to configure an alternative FBA log-in page (where users provide their username and password), but for the authentication provider selection page we're at a loss. Any ideas? Or there is no other wan other than replacing the file like we're doing?

We are concerned that replacing original out of the box files is not a great solution since they are likely to be overwritten by SharePoint updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your solution and then simply modify the Web Application Sign In Page in Central Administration. This is done via Manage Web Applications, highlight the Web App, click Auth Providers, select the provider, and specify the new page URL. On this page you would customize the links to your authentication provider URLs.

Comment: Actually my understanding is that only seems to update the FBA sign in page. Not the provider selection page. Did I miss something? We have customised our provider selection page by adding our logo and replacing the dropdown with bigger buttons (touch friendly). We still want to allow users to select their authentication method (ADFS or FBA).

Comment: The solution is outlined here in Option 2: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2014/10/31/bypassing-multiple-authentication-providers-in-sharepoint-2013/. On the custom login page, you would just have your own version of the selector that looks nicer.

Comment: Just one question about the solution yo shared (option 2) above. The author starts by saying that we need to make a backup of the default.aspx page. Doesn't that mean that his solution also replaces the default "default.aspx" file? The whole idea is that we do not replace default files and point sharepoint to alternate files instead.

Comment: You can rename the file and just set the custom login page with whatever your page name is.

Comment: I am going to have my more senior developers to look into this. Gotta say that it DID went over my head :-p

Comment: Here is what one developer told me: "This [seems to be] just for bypassing Windows auth when you have both windows and ADFS. So a user goes straight to ADFS". Is he right? Because we really want to support both ADFS and FBA.

Comment: No. I've used this for a SAML + LDAP solution before.